# Ошибка: ReferenceError: flushJSON is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему возникает эта ошибка?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $data = $('#motor_flush_data');

    $.getJSON('https://www.amag.ru/motor_flush/selector.json', function(data){

      flushJSON = data;

      var items = [];

      items = getObj(data,0);

      $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'my-new-list',
        html: items
      }).prependTo($data);
    });

    $('.flush_select_box', $data).hide();


});

function next(obj){

    var dataKey = obj.getAttribute('data-key');
    var openId = getOpenID(dataKey);

    openId = openId.concat(0,'FN','HG');
    openId.reverse();



    $('.flush_select_box').hide();

    for(var i=0; i<openId.length; i++){
        $('#box-'+openId[i]).fadeIn();
    }

    var level = $(obj).parent().parent().data('level');
    if (level)
    {
        $('.flush_select_box[data-level='+(level+1)+'] .ans').removeClass("active");

    }


    $(obj).addClass("active")
            .siblings().removeClass("active");

    $(".flush_select_box .motor_is_ok").removeClass("motor_is_ok");


    $('#box-'+dataKey).fadeIn();

    if ($(window).width() <= 767)
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $('#box-'+dataKey).offset().top - $(".header-top").height()});

    $(".flush_result_title").hide();
    $('#motor_flush_result').html('');

    $.each(flushJSON[dataKey]["a"], function(key, val){
        if(key === 'Hi-Gear') {
            $(".flush_result_title").show();

            if (!$("#motor_flush_result .loader").length)
                $("#motor_flush_result").append('<div class="loader"><div></div></div>');

            $.ajax("/motor_flush/ajax.php", {
                type: "POST",
                data:{"article": val},
                success:function(data){
                    $("#motor_flush_result .loader").remove()
                    $('#motor_flush_result .higear').remove();
                    $('#motor_flush_result').html($('#motor_flush_result').html() + '<div class="flush_result_block higear"><h2>абаОаДбаКбб аЛаИаНаЕаЙаКаИ Hi-Gear</h2>' + data + "</div>");


                    if ($(window).width() > 767)
                    {

                        if ($("#motor_flush_modal").length)
                            $("#motor_flush_modal #motor_flush_div").stop().animate({scrollTop: $("#motor_flush_modal #motor_flush_div").scrollTop() + $(obj).parent().parent().position().top});
                        else
                            $("html, body").stop().animate({scrollTop: $(obj).parent().parent().offset().top - $(".header-top").height()});
                    }

                }
            })

        } else if(key === 'FENOM') {
            $(".flush_result_title").show();

            if (!$("#motor_flush_result .loader").length)
                $("#motor_flush_result").append('<div class="loader"><div></div></div>');

            $.ajax("/motor_flush/ajax.php", {
                type: "POST",
                data:{"article": val},
                success:function(data){

                    $('#motor_flush_result .fenom').remove();
                    $("#motor_flush_result .loader").remove()
                    $('#motor_flush_result').html($('#motor_flush_result').html() + '<div class="flush_result_block fenom"><h2>абаОаДбаКбб аЛаИаНаЕаЙаКаИ FENOM</h2>' + data + "</div>");

                    if ($(window).width() > 767)
                    {

                        if ($("#motor_flush_modal").length)
                            $("#motor_flush_modal #motor_flush_div").stop().animate({scrollTop: $("#motor_flush_modal #motor_flush_div").scrollTop() + $(obj).parent().parent().position().top});

                        else
                            $("html, body").stop().animate({scrollTop: $(obj).parent().parent().offset().top - $(".header-top").height()});
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Ошибка в этой строке:

```
$.each(flushJSON[dataKey]["a"], function(key, val){
```

с ошибкой:

> ReferenceError: flushJSON is not defined

Comment: Причём здесь java?

Answer (score -1):

`flushJSON` не объявлена, либо ей ещё не присвоено значение (undefined).

Учитывайте порядок вызова функций. На момент вызова `next()` данные от сервера ещё могут быть не получены, а могут быть получены и == `undefined`. В любом случае, перед использованием flushJSON проверьте, есть ли в ней то что вам нужно и существует ли переменная.